# some transactions are not tracked in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce

I'm having trouble with google analytics e-commerce report: I see that about one-third of transactions are not tracked including my personal orders. I use [ga_debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en) to find the problem. In ga_debugger console, it is reported that:
"Aborting cookie write: User has opted out of tracking".
I just have no idea about this report. Any suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the visitor opted out of being tracked.  Read the Google Analytics [Privacy Policy](http://www.google.com/analytics/learn/privacy.html) for details on how visitors can do this, particularly the **Privacy Controls** section.

Comment: thank you for your response. someone installs Google Analytics Opt-out Add-on on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the **Google Analytics Opt-out Add-on** is enabled.

*In Chrome, go to Settings... , Extensions...*

If you see this Add-on, uncheck the Enabled box or remove the Add-on entirely. [image]